# Do XCode projects need special settings to use pre-compiled boost libraries?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, boost

I have just installed boost for the first time on my Intel Mac, and it works fine in general, as long as I use only boost's header files.

But when I try to use a lib, in my case the regex lib, my app links and launches fine, but then it soon crashes in a regex related destructor.

This even happens with the simple test program that's given on [boost.org's unix install page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#link-your-program-to-a-boost-library) .

I wonder if I need to set special compile/link options (I've used the defaults for a C++ Tool) other than setting the search paths and including the regex lib, of course?

(BTW, I have verified that the default compiler on my system is indeed gcc 4.01, which is the same my test project in XCode uses)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to self:

While it's still not clear what causes this problem, there is a workaround:

Instead of using the libs that the boost installer process builds, add the source code for the lib (in boost-main-folder/libs/*libname*/src/) to your Xcode project instead, having Xcode compile the sources for you.

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is old, but now even with Boost 1.53 this still happens. I was answered in an another later thread—cross-linking in case someone finds this one via Google or other search.

[Recompiling with the C++11 option does the trick. Apparently that is not default with clang.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12695625/boost-test-crashes-on-exit-with-clang-4-1-llvm-3-1svn?answertab=active#tab-top)