# Boost test crashes on exit with Clang 4.1 (LLVM 3.1svn)

Tags: c++, macos, boost, segmentation-fault, clang

Consider this simple program:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE "MyTest"
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

using namespace std;

template<char* S>
void Test()
{
    BOOST_REQUIRE("Boom!" != string(S));
}

char bang[] = "Bang!";

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(Boom)
{
    char boom[] = "Boom!";
    Test<bang>();
}
```

I'm on [Mac OS X v10.8.2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mountain_Lion) (Mountain Lion) and have [XCode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode) 4.5 installed.

The program works when compiled with [GCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection), for example,

```
gcc test.cpp -lboost_unit_test_framework-mt -lstdc++
```

but it crashes when compiled with Apple [Clang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang) 4.1 (tags/Apple/clang-421.11.65) (based on [LLVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLVM) 3.1svn)

```
clang -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -lc++ test.cpp -lboost_unit_test_framework-mt
```

I'm using Boost 1.51.0, installed using BREW. Recompiling Boost using Clang does not help.

Is there a solution to this mystery?

```
./a.out
Running 1 test case...

*** No errors detected
Segmentation fault: 11

gdb ./a.out
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1822) (Sun Aug  5 03:00:42 UTC 2012)
...
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin"...Reading symbols for shared libraries .... done

(gdb) r
Starting program: /private/tmp/xx/a.out 
Reading symbols for shared libraries +++............................. done
Running 1 test case...

*** No errors detected

Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: 13 at address: 0x0000000000000000
0x0000000100056c56 in boost::unit_test::test_unit::~test_unit ()
(gdb) where
#0  0x0000000100056c56 in boost::unit_test::test_unit::~test_unit ()
#1  0x000000010002435f in boost::unit_test::master_test_suite_t::~master_test_suite_t ()
#2  0x00000001000244dd in boost::unit_test::framework_impl::~framework_impl ()
#3  0x00007fff96179307 in __cxa_finalize ()
#4  0x00007fff9617af57 in exit ()
#5  0x00007fff944897e8 in start ()

lldb a.out
Current executable set to 'a.out' (x86_64).
(lldb) r
Process 71553 launched: '/private/tmp/xx/a.out' (x86_64)
Running 1 test case...

*** No errors detected
Process 71553 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x1c03, 0x0000000100056c56 libboost_unit_test_framework.dylib`boost::unit_test::test_unit::~test_unit() + 86, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=13, address=0x0)
    frame #0: 0x0000000100056c56 libboost_unit_test_framework.dylib`boost::unit_test::test_unit::~test_unit() + 86
libboost_unit_test_framework.dylib`boost::unit_test::test_unit::~test_unit() + 86:
-> 0x100056c56:  lock   
   0x100056c57:  xaddl  %ecx, -8(%rax)
   0x100056c5b:  testl  %ecx, %ecx
   0x100056c5d:  jg     0x100056c68               ; boost::unit_test::test_unit::~test_unit() + 104

clang --version
Apple clang version 4.1 (tags/Apple/clang-421.11.65) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0
Thread model: posix
```

Answer (score 10):

Recompiling Boost with the C++11 options does the trick.

```
./bootstrap.sh --with-toolset=clang --prefix=/usr/local
sudo ./b2 install toolset=clang cxxflags="-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++" linkflags="-stdlib=libc++" threading=multi
```

I made a mistake of using just `./b2 install` last time but the install step appears to build some libraries before installing them.

Comment: Great catch! I was getting a segfault 11 using the current version of boost still (1.56.0) and on Yosemite. I had just accepted the default install using brew via bottle - but instead had to do a `brew install boost --c++11` (use `brew options boost` to see all options).

Comment: HOWEVER... this ultimately didn't work. I had to use `cmake .. -DBoost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=YES` to compel cmake to link in statically for it to work... Still investigating why:-(

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue than timlukins.
I had to do `cmake .. -DBoost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=YES`. But as I had other issues compiling with boost_timer for instance, I found that it was my include that was not correct.

I had to replace :

```
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
```

with:

```
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
```

It was working fine with gcc and VS13, but not with clang.
If it can help...

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work, but you may need the other arguments.

```
USER (~/tmp)
$ clang++ -pedantic test.cpp -lboost_unit_test_framework-mt 

USER (~/tmp)
$ ./a.out 
Running 1 test case...

*** No errors detected
```

Comment: Did you try the C++11 options as per my original post? Does it work when you do?

Comment: Yes, it's the -stdlib=libc++  that makes the difference