# Clang causes segfault with boost library g++ works. OS X

Tags: c++, macos, boost, c++11

I'm using the `boost/iostreams/filtering/gzip.hpp` library and for some reason it works with g++ (4.2 - the ancient version, which is pre-installed on macs), but compiling exactly the same code with clang++ causes a seg-fault:

```
std::ifstream file(fname.c_str(), std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);
boost::iostreams::filtering_istream in;
in.push(boost::iostreams::gzip_decompressor()); // This line causes the segfault
in.push(file);
```

I have no idea what is causing the problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have a version of boost compiled with -std=c++11?

Comment: I followed the instructions in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12695625/boost-test-crashes-on-exit-with-clang-4-1-llvm-3-1svn) thread, but it didn't seem to make a difference. Is there any way to double check that the libraries I'm linking to were built with -std=c++11?

Comment: I don't know how to check it.

Comment: Also note that if you build with `-std=c++11`, you also need to add `-stdlib=libc++` (in general, make sure that your executable and libs are linking to the same stdlib (I believe the default on OS X is libstdc++, which doesn't have C++11 support)).

Comment: Is the compiler segfaulting, or the resulting binary?

Comment: I strongly suspect this is because the program and boost itself haven't been compiled with the same compiler options (as mentioned specifically `-std` and `-stdlib`).  Please rebuild boost and try again.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies! I finally got it to work. Turns out they changed the library name from `lboost_iostreams-mt` to `lboost_iostreams`, so even though I had the correctly compiled version installed, it was still linking to the old version. Guess I should have made sure to remove the old boost libraries first!